# protobuf C++ SQLite handle blob data

Tags: c++, blob, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I have a SQLite database which has a table which contains some fields of BLOB type.
What I am trying to do is fetch the field (in fact all other fields too) from the database into C++ send it through protobuf and receive the protobuf .

I have defined the blob fields as `bytes` in the `.proto` file
For example

```
message fields{
    ...
    bytes myBlobField = 1;
}
```

My c++ file contains

```
sqlite3_initialize();
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(db_url, &db,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,NULL);
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "select * from attribtable ";
std::string query = oss.str();

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query.c_str(),-1,&stmt,NULL

while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){

    sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,10) //This is the blob field
}
```

How do I store the `sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,10)` in C++ and how do I set `myBlobField` using 
say `reply->set_myblobfield(??)`

and receive on the client side using

`say receive->get_myblobfield()`

So in simple words my question is how do I send the blobfield fetched from database, through protobuf, from server to client in a C++ application?

Comment: What does `fields` pre-process into ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Can You throw more light on what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Using this .proto file

```
syntax = "proto2";

package prototest;

message fields{
    required bytes myBlobField = 1;
}
```

You initialize the blob using the `set_myblobfield()` call with the blob pointer and the byte size of the blob which you get from SQLite and then call the `SerializeToOstream()` method to write it to a stream or to a file.

```
std::ofstream myoutput("myoutput.bin");

while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    if (size_t blobSize = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 10))
    {
        if (const void* blob = sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 10))
        {
            prototest::fields myfields;
            myfields.set_myblobfield(blob, blobSize);

            myfields.SerializeToOstream(&myoutput);
        }
    }
}
```